# What is the $\gamma''(2)$ for the curve $\gamma(t) = (t^2+4t,8t^2-t^3,t^3-4t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

This looks like a very silly question. But, I'm very serious for this.

For the curve $\gamma(t) = (t^2+4t,8t^2-t^3,t^3-4t), t>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The question required finding the $a+b+c$ for the $\gamma''(2) = aT +bN+cB$.

In my thought, Since the $\gamma'(2) = vT$ Therefore, $\gamma''= v'T + (\kappa v^2 N)$.

So the $a = v'$, $b=\kappa v^2$ and $c=0$. (Here the $v$ is the velocity of the $\gamma$).

But the solution written in the note said  $\gamma''= v'T + (-\kappa v^2 N)$. I can't understand why the $b=-\kappa v^2$. In my opinion, It would be typo. Am I right?

Comment: Could be a typo, could also be a non-standard sign-convention. At any rate, you seem to have a $v$ too much in both $v (\kappa v^2 N)$ and $v(-\kappa v^2 N)$

Comment: To clarify the above comment: $\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{dT}{ds}\cdot\frac{ds}{dt} = (\kappa N) \cdot v.$ So $\gamma'' = v'T + vT' = v'T + v(\kappa vN).$ (and adding negative signs for $N$ if we're working with the alternative sign convention)

Comment: @sbares, Oh yes. I edited my post. :) Thank you.